# Get specific html portion with regex string matching in php

Tags: php, regex

i am trying to get specific **HTML** code portion with regex **preg_match_all** by matching it with **class tag** But it is returning empty array.

This is the html portion which i want to get from complete **HTML**

```
<div class="details">
    <div class="title">
        <a href="citation.cfm?id=2892225&CFID=598850954&CFTOKEN=15595705"   
        target="_self">Restrictification of function arguments</a>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Where I am using this **regex**

```
preg_match_all('~<div class=\'details\'>\s*(<div.*?</div>\s*)?(.*?)</div>~is', $html, $matches );
```

**NOTE:** $html variable is having the whole html from which I want to search.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe it's because you used the wrong quotes at \'details\' (-> \"details\" or ["']details["'])

Comment: What should the output be (in your example)?

Comment: using regex for the first time, i assume it should give the content inside the <div>. I don't know exactly how it will return the output.

Comment: inside the "title" div or the "details" div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for single quotes in your regex in contrast to the double quotes in `$html`.

Your regex should look like:

```
'~<div class="details">\s*(<div.*?</div>\s*)?(.*?)</div>~is'
```

or better:

```
'~<div class=[\'"]details[\'"]>\s*(<div.*?</div>\s*)?(.*?)</div>~is'
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. i am still getting empty array.
I used as you told:
preg_match_all('~<div class=[\'"]details[\'"]>\s*(<div.*?</div>\s*)?(.*?)</div>~is', $html, $matches );

Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: I tried the test case you've shown and `$matches` isn't empty over here.

Comment: can you please please post full code you're trying? (or i could share mine)

Comment: Please update your question to show more code, as I'm not doing anything different than you're doing (as shown by now).

Comment: Your code is working. I was using html_entities function which was removing tags (yes i am terrible at this).
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Better use a `DOM` approach !

```
<?php
$html = '<div class="details">
    <div class="title">
        <a href="citation.cfm?id=2892225&CFID=598850954&CFTOKEN=15595705"   
        target="_self">Restrictification of function arguments</a>  
    </div>
</div>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$divs = $xpath->query('//div[@class="title"]');
print_r($divs);
?>
```

Comment: Which is definitely the better approach than doing the regex.

Comment: Not sure that printing a DOMNodeList object will give the attempted result.

Comment: thanks but its for my class work, i have to use it with regex

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: It will certainly not, just to make sure any element has been found.